# Embedded Jetty: A ServletContext is required to configure default servlet handling

Tags: java, spring-boot, jetty

I'm trying to setup a spring boot app with an embedded jetty server. This server shall run a small webapp. However, when starting I get the following exception, just after the war file has been loaded.

**Trace**

```
2016-10-02 16:07:59.302 ERROR 18765 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultServletHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping]: Factory method 'defaultServletHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A ServletContext is required to configure default servlet handling
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839) ~[spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538) ~[spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) ~[spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.5.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping]: Factory method 'defaultServletHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A ServletContext is required to configure default servlet handling
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A ServletContext is required to configure default servlet handling
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:115) ~[spring-core-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer.<init>(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer.java:53) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.defaultServletHandlerMapping(WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java:451) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$671a10db.CGLIB$defaultServletHandlerMapping$28(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$671a10db$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$f33d99c3.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:356) ~[spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$671a10db.defaultServletHandlerMapping(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_111]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_111]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    ... 25 common frames omitted
```

I've trimmed down the code to a minimum and still get the error.

**Main**

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class ServerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ServerApplication.class);
    }

}
```

**Configuration**

```
@Configuration

@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class JettyServerCustomizer implements EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer {

    @Override
    public void customize(ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer container) {
        if (container instanceof JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory) {
            customizeJetty((JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory) container);
        }
    }

    public void customizeJetty(
            JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory containerFactory) {
        containerFactory.addServerCustomizers(jettyServerCustomizer());
    }

    @Bean
    public JettyServerCustomizer jettyServerCustomizer() {
        return new JettyServerCustomizer() {

            @Override
            public void customize(Server server) {
                String jetty_home = System.getProperty("jetty.home","..");
                WebAppContext webapp = new WebAppContext();
                webapp.setContextPath("/");
                webapp.setWar(jetty_home+"/webapps/sample.war");
                server.setHandler(webapp);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Any suggestions? Thanks!

**Update**

After trying the suggestion from Strelok i get this error instead.

```
2016-10-02 16:55:03.715  INFO 20025 --- [           main] org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder  : unavailable

java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initMultiPart(ServletHolder.java:702) [jetty-servlet-9.2.16.v20160414.jar!/:9.2.16.v20160414]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:607) [jetty-servlet-9.2.16.v20160414.jar!/:9.2.16.v20160414]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initialize(ServletHolder.java:396) [jetty-servlet-9.2.16.v20160414.jar!/:9.2.16.v20160414]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:871) [jetty-servlet-9.2.16.v20160414.jar!/:9.2.16.v20160414]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.jetty.JettyEmbeddedWebAppContext$JettyEmbeddedServletHandler.deferredInitialize(JettyEmbeddedWebAppContext.java:46) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.jetty.JettyEmbeddedWebAppContext.deferredInitialize(JettyEmbeddedWebAppContext.java:36) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.jetty.JettyEmbeddedServletContainer.handleDeferredInitialize(JettyEmbeddedServletContainer.java:167) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.jetty.JettyEmbeddedServletContainer.handleDeferredInitialize(JettyEmbeddedServletContainer.java:170) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.jetty.JettyEmbeddedServletContainer.start(JettyEmbeddedServletContainer.java:114) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.startEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:293) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:141) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541) [spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.5.RELEASE]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to reuse the handler from the Server:

```
return new JettyServerCustomizer() {

        @Override
        public void customize(Server server) {
            String jetty_home = System.getProperty("jetty.home","..");
            WebAppContext webapp = new WebAppContext();
            webapp.setContextPath("/");
            webapp.setWar(jetty_home+"/webapps/sample.war");
            webapp.setHandler(server.getHandler());
            server.setHandler(webapp);
        }
    };
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply. Tried this and got another error instead. Please see updated post.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs due to `WebMvc` support being enabled. This can occur due to a configuration class containing `@EnableWebMvc`, but also due to auto configuration. Try excluding the `WebMvc` auto configuration.

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {WebMvcAutoConfiguration.class, WebMvcAutoConfiguration.EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class, WebMvcAutoConfiguration.WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter.class})
```

In my case, I needed the `WebMvc` support, so I obtained access to the `@Configuration` class which inherited from `WebMvcConfigurationSupport` and set the servlet context with a Jetty configuration to fix the NPE.

```
@Bean
public org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.Configuration jettyConfiguration() {
    return new AbstractConfiguration() {
        @Override
        public void configure(WebAppContext context) throws Exception {
            // This line fixes the error in my case
            config.setServletContext(context.getServletContext());
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Nice, I'll try this.

Comment: Excluding WebMvc didn't fix the problem. Tried the second part. How do I get access to the config class that inherits from WebMvcConfigurationSuport? Thanks.

Comment: Eric, if you could provide a sample that would be of great assistance. I am having the same issue with Spring Boot 2.0.1 and Jetty 9.4.8.*